# type inference when using templates

Tags: c++, templates, types, inference

So here is what I would like to do: I use `std::pair`, but I would surely like to do the same using tuples, or indeed pretty much any kind of template. When assigning a pair variable, I need to type something like:

```
T1 t1;
T2 t2;
std::pair<T1,T2> X;
X = std::pair<T1,T2> (t1, t2);
```

Is there a way to omit the second `<T1,T2>` when creating the new pair, and let the compiler guess, either using X's type (I'm obviously trying to create a `pair<T1,T2>`) or `t1` and `t2`'s types (I am building a pair with a `T1` object and a `T2` object, there is a chance the pair I want is of type `pair<T1,T2>`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but template argument deduction only works on function templates, not constructors of class templates. For this reason, the library provides a function:

```
X = std::make_pair(t1, t2);
```

In C++11, pairs and tuples can be initialised and assigned from initialiser lists:

```
X = {t1, t2};
```

or `auto` can be used to automatically specify the type from the initialiser, so you don't need to specify the template arguments at all:

```
auto X = std::make_pair(t1, t2);
```

Comment: Do you know the reason why template argument deduction is not allowed for constructors ?

Comment: @Hephaestos: I don't know the reason; but I think it might be very hard, if not impossible, to deduce them in the general case, since different class template specialisations can have different sets of constructors. That's just a guess, though,

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `std::make_pair`:

```
std::pair<T1,T2> X;
// some code
X = std::make_pair( t1, t2 );
```

Or, if you can initialize it directly:

```
std::pair<T1,T2> X = std::make_pair( t1, t2 ); // OR, even better:
std::pair<T1,T2> X( t1, t2 );
```

---

For C++11, initializing is even better:

```
auto X = std::make_pair( t1, t2 );
```

The assignment is the same:

```
X = std::make_pair( t1, t2 );
```

but it could also be:

```
X = { t1, t2 };
```

Comment: OP is assigning to ``X``, not copy-initializing, so ``auto`` doesn't apply (but is surely useful to know about).

Comment: thank you, the answer was right under my nose as I expected :D

Comment: Can we use initializer list for an assignment ?

Comment: @Hephaestos - yes, in C++11, for `std::pair`, as I have written.

Comment: @Hephaestos - if your compiler does not support it, just use `std::make_pair`, as show at the very beginning of my answer..

Comment: Ok thank you (I thought initializer lists were only for initialization).

Answer (score 3):

```
std::pair<T1,T2> X = std::make_pair(t1, t2);
```

or with `C++11`

```
std::pair<T1, T2> X = {t1, t2};
```

or with `C++11`

```
auto X = std::make_pair(t1, t2);
```

And for `std::tuple` there is `std::make_tuple`.

Comment: Why not `std::pair<T1,T2> x(t1, t2);`? This should be fine with pre C++11, too.

Comment: @Nobody well, OP is assigning to ``X``, and this answer is all about declaration and initialization, which is kind of irrelevant here.